# Can't search for tweets in a particular span with twitteR. (R package)

Tags: r, twitter, r-package

I am planning to extract tweets for a particular span using the R package twitteR.

```
data<- searchTwitter("Kohli",n=100, lang="en", since="2014-12-01", until="2014-12-30",cainfo="cacert.pem")
```

But I am getting this message

```
In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  :
  100 tweets were requested but the API can only return 0
```

I can search for tweets without the since and until parameters.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just recently it changed where you can only extract a week's worth of tweets. 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf